# Using the Charts framework. Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, charts, frameworks

Im trying to follow the following tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

I drag the Charts.xcodeproj into my project and within the general section and 'linked frameworks and libraries' it already has the charts frameworks added:

[image: linked frameworks and libraries screenshot]

However i get the following errors:

[image: Error message img]

On the instructions its says 'In the General tab on the right, locate the Embedded Binaries section and hit the + in this section to add the charts framework. Select Charts.framework from the list and click Add.' However I can't find the 'embedded binaries' so I assumed this was an earlier version of Xcode and i am meant to be looking at 'linked frameworks and libraries' however i may be wrong!

Any help would be appriciated :)

Comment: Problems like this arise a lot with this method of integration and are hard to debug. Are you familiar with using CocoaPods as a package manager to import libraries into your project? It's a much cleaner method and ultimately I believe would lead to a solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi Shen, I got past this problem (See below) however now I have imported the embedded binaries I am just getting "Build failed" and no reason. I am not familiar with CocoaPods.

Comment: Strange. I would clean the project and attempt to rebuild. But on to CocoaPods... I would definitely take time to do a tutorial. I see the appcoda tutorial mentions it as a option. It's pretty much industry standard to do it this way. It's going to save you headaches in the future, especially when you need to update or remove libraries. Good luck, ios-charts is a terrific library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this problem. I had clicked on the 'Charts.xcodeproj' and tried to find 'Embedded Link'. This is wrong.

Click on your project name and above the 'deployment target' select your project target (with the pencil image).

[image]

Now the 'embedded Binaries' option is available:

[image]